# "the more ....., the more..." examples

Tags: grammar

I am trying to learn this structure, but when I write a sentence down I feel that the sentence is not natural enough, so please help me to correct the following sentences:

- The harder I study, the better score I can get in IELTS exam.
- The larger the number of people interested in art, the happier the society is.
- The more fitness centres is available, the healthier the people is.
- The smaller **the\no article** farmland is, the less food is produced.

I will appreciate giving me more examples.

Comment: Could you please add some detail explaining why you feel this structure is confusing?  We don't do simple correction, but we can help you with general concepts.

Comment: [I would appreciate your giving me more examples].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.thoughtco.com/double-comparatives-1210274 
Here is a link that deals exhaustively with double comparatives. As you did not tell us where the shoe pinches no specific answer could be provided. This far can be said that when two things or beings are are so intertwined one has a direct bearing in an equally proportionate way either to increase or decrease or vice-versa, we take the help of double comparatives. Here are its salient points:

- The comparatives have THE before them
- It can have the structure of " more...more" , " less ... less", " more...less", " less...more" or  comparative form(s)in any of the two adjectives and the other supplemented by " more/less " or both the adjectives in their comparative forms.
- They are used in statements, cliches or commands.
- Balance of the portion after each comparative should be so maintained that none becomes over burdened. However there are exceptions.

We leave it to you to formulate your comparisons.

The last of your example sentences must have THE before the noun,  farmland;  otherwise they all are grammatical.